# Look at Column A, Match With Column E, Copy Column B to Column F

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So I am sure this is easy if you know your way around VBA, I just havnet been able to get it to work for me.

This is an example of the table I have. I want to move everything into a single row if column A is the same. This is the table, with what I am expecting also.

```
A   B    C         D            E     F          G        H         I
11  Yes Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46  11  Yes 8/1/2013 20:46  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46
11  No  Blue    8/1/2013 20:46  12  Yes 8/1/2013 20:46  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46
11  YY  Red 8/1/2013 20:46      13  Yes 8/1/2013 20:46   Red    8/1/2013 20:46
11  NN  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
11  YYY Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
11  NNN Blue    8/1/2013 20:46                  
11  YYYYY   Red 8/1/2013 20:46                  
11  NNNN    Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  Yes Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  No  Blue    8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  YY  Red 8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  NN  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  YYY Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
12  NNN Blue    8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  Yes Red 8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  No  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  YY  Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  NN  Blue    8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  YYY Red 8/1/2013 20:46                  
13  NNN Yellow  8/1/2013 20:46
```

This is what I was trying to do with VBA. Not the best but I was trying.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row


    With ws
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If range("A" & i).Value = range("E" & i) Then range("f" & i).Value = range("b" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with the VBA needed to get this done. I am having issues with the loop to cycle and compare each A value to each value in E.

Comment: Could it be that you're comparing A with C?  Your title says a, e, b, f but your loop says a, c, b, f...

Comment: Sorry it should be A to E, let me adjust to code. I will also edit to show what I am trying to get to in final results.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I would do this with formulas in excel - your code says if E=A, then make F=B for each row. From your question though, I read it as you want all of the items from the first list horizontally against the table starting in E

Comment: Can you show the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure what you want to achieve. But I have made a code based on my understanding. Just try it out.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastRowA As Long, lastRowB As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With ws
        For i = 1 To lastRowE
            CurrentEValue = Range("E" & i).Value
            MatchFound = False
            For j = 1 To lastRowA
                CurrentAValue = Range("A" & j).Value
                If CurrentAValue = CurrentEValue And Not MatchFound Then
                    Range("f" & i).Value = Range("b" & j).Value
                    MatchFound = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Few things I will need to adjust to meet exact needs and adapt it. But this is what I was trying to get done. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to put the data in lines 1 to 8, column B to D, into line 1, column F and following, because for lines 1 to 8 the '11' in column A matches the '11' in E1?
E.g. B1->F1, C1->H1 (this is the first position where I'm missing some order), D1->G1, ??->I1 (where does the content from column I come from?),
(append the next source line in the same target line:) B2->J1, ...

First of all you need to clarify where the data in cols F to I (and further) comes from.
Then:
If my assumption about your intention is right, then this brings up other questions:

- Does col E always contain all possible values of col A or might there be values (e.g. '14') in col A that are missing in col E?
- Are the positions of the values in col E fixed?

Here are some suggestions, code might follow after clarification:

- Determine the number of lines in col A
- Determine the number of lines in col E
- Use 2 loops: one outer loop for taking the data from col A and an inner loop to search the taken data in col E
- use ws.cells(row, col).value instead of range()
- if you want to append the data from different source lines in the same target line, add a array variable that keeps the position of the next free columns for each target row.

General suggestions:

- Don't use the variable names like 'i'. Unclear variable names come along with many disadvantages. Use iRow or something similar instead (easy to handle for search and replace, a distinct meaining, information about the variable type (i=integer), ...)
- use Option Explicit at the top of the module. This will force you to declare all variables explicitly and ensure the correct usage of variables.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will use this in the future.